# Chrome not displaying divs properly when using Flexie, (IE works fine)

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm trying to have 3 divs side-by-side, with any remaining divs getting pushed to the next row. The follow jsFiddle works perfectly in IE, but in Chrome it only shows the parent div (box-wrap).  [See demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ekkfe51f/3/)

However, if I remove "float:left;" from the #box-wrap-inner div, the divs will then appear, but the 4th div is outside the parent (far right). It should be displayed underneath div 1. [See demo 2 here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ekkfe51f/2/)

In IE however, the 4th div is properly positioned underneath div 1, as you can see in the screenshot below. What is causing Chrome to not display the divs properly when "float:left;" is added?

The main HTML code is:

```
<div id="box-wrap">
            <div id="box-wrap-inner">
                <div id="box-1">Box 1</div>
                <div id="box-2">Box 2</div>
                <div id="box-3">Box 4</div>
                <div id="box-3">Box 3</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and the css that's causing problems is:

```
#box-wrap-inner div {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #8ec1da;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Any help would be so great! Thank you

**Working properly in IE**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use:

```
#box-wrap-inner {
    /* Display Box */
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: box;
}
```

Just remove above `display: -webkit-box;` and it's work in chrome:

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/ekkfe51f/16/) Here.